# Map EFCore to oracle custom composite type

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, entity-framework-core

So I have a table containing a column of type...let's call it STAMP:

```
CREATE TYPE STAMP( 
    timestamp DATE, 
    num INTEGER 
)
```

So naturally, my EF model has a property of type Stamp:

```
public class Stamp
{
  public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
  public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

Yet I get the error `The property Table.From is of type 'Stamp' which is not supported by the current database provider`.

How can I map that? The [EFCore issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/246) seems to be closed.

Comment: Which issue? As I know current Oracle ADO.NET provider do not support such types mapping.

Comment: I added the link to the question - it's one on the EFCore repo.

Comment: Well, this issue is not the same case that you have. Enjoy https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56. Then you have to wait when Oracle EF Core provider will handle that. Probably `Devart` DataProvider may have such feature.

Comment: Oh, now I know they're called UDT, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called User Defined Type (UDT). Currently it is not supported by Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core. And for sure it is not supported by EF Core Oracle provider.

Tracking issue: https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56